# Android - How Can I let a CountDownCounter change a TextView

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, android-databinding

since I can't find anything similar, and I can't figure out why it isn't working, can someone help me out?

I got a little android app that uses one *main activity* and the rest of the app consists of fragments.
In this one fragment I have a counter which should update a TextView which is connected to a variable in my ViewFragment via DataBinding. This is my timer and timerText is the variable which is binded through the layout xml.

```
  private val timer = object : CountDownTimer(R.integer.defaultTimeMilli.toLong(), 1000) {
    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        timerText = (millisUntilFinished/1000).toString()
    }

    override fun onFinish() {
       _timerIsFinished.value = true
    }
}
```

The text isn't updated in my fragment on the ticks, even tho the timer gets started. If you need more stuff from my code just ask. Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Here is the part of the XML file that is relevant:

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{gameFragmentViewModel.timerText}"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pointsTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.228" />
```

Comment: Try using postValue instead of setValue.

Answer (score 0):

Found out why it wasnt working.
Put the string into a LiveData variable if you use Databinding like I do.
That means I now got

```
private var _timerText = MutableLiveData<String>()
val timerText : LiveData<String>
    get() = _timerText
```

timerText is the one referred to by the Layout-XML and _timerText is edited by the timer.